# Cakephp 3 how to pass a variable to Contain query?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm doing a query where i also want to retrieve associated data with the Contain argument.

The Contain subquery must be conditioned because i want only certain data, i followed [Passing Conditions to Contain](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain) but i want to send a variable too and thats when i get this error:

> Warning (2): Missing argument 2 for
>   App\Controller\Admin\UsuariosController::App\Controller\Admin{closure}(),
>   called in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/faindit/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association/SelectableAssociationTrait.php
>   on line 54 and defined [APP/Controller/Admin/UsuariosController.php,
>   line 212]

and this:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: rol
>   [APP/Controller/Admin/UsuariosController.php, line 217]

The variable is defined but the Cointain function is not receiving it. Which is the proper way to do this??

```
$rol = 1;

$countRoles = $rolesTable->find('all', [      
  'order'=>'Roles.nombre asc'
])->contain([
  'Usuarios'=> function($q, $rol){   
    return $q
      ->select(['Usuarios.rol_id'])
      ->where([
        'Usuarios.estado'=>$rol
    ]);
  }
])->toArray();
```

Comment: Found my solution there, thanks!!